# JQuery, create element with dynamic class

Tags: javascript, jquery, properties, dynamically-generated

I am trying to create elements with dynamic class value, so far unsuccessful. Here's code:

```
let sender = "alex";
let message = "testMsg";
let time = "15:30";
let msg = $('<span>')
              .append($('<span>', {class : 'timestamp'}, {text: time}))
              .append($('<p>', {class : sender}, {text: message}));
```

Results in the following:

```
<span>
    <span id="timestamp"></span>
    <p></p>
</span>
```

Which is confusing, because I read [here](https://coderwall.com/p/evmqoa/creating-dom-elements-with-jquery-in-a-more-elegant-way) that this more "elegant" way allows for variables to be used as dynamical properties. What am I missing here?

Thanks

*Solved: Turns out that I tried to give 3 paramethers to .append() function. Read bellow for solutions and explanation.*

Comment: There are too many errors in this code, so I guess it's not the real one. Can you build a runnable snippet ? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You could use jQuery [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: Oftopic but why are using ``let`` instead of ``var``?

Comment: @DenysSéguret I fixed span and added 'time' variable, only errors I can find. This is the code I am running to produce the above results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, Here are small changes which I have done:

1. Specify tag properly it should be `<span>` not `</span>`
2. Use correct API, you can pass multiple arguments. `$('<span />', {class: 'timestamp', text: time })`
3. Define all variables i.e. `time` was not defined.
4. should not insert a `<p>` inside a `<span>`, Pointed out by [@blex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1913729/blex)

```js
let sender = "alex",
  message = "testMsg",
  time = '15:30';

let msg = $('<span>')
  .append($('<span>', {
    class: 'timestamp',
    text: time
  }))
  .append($('<p>', {
    class: sender,
    text: message
  }));

$('div').append(msg)
```

```css
.alex{color:green}
.timestamp{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: In fact it shouldn't even be `<span/>` (which works because the engine is lax but isn't valid) but  `<span>`

Comment: @DenysSéguret The jQuery documentation [uses the `"<span/>"` syntax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#example-1-1)

Comment: @blex ok, that's still a terrible practice. It assumes the browsers parses invalid HTML the way you want it to do it.

Comment: [The snippet works, but I still don't get any class. Why would that be?] Never mind, fixed it. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
let sender = "alex";
let message = "testMsg";
let time = "15:30";
let msg = $('<span>')
                  .append($('<span>', {class : 'timestamp', text: time}))
                  .append($('<p>', {class : sender, text: message}));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/MostafaB/hhadxdxe/

Comment: Why another identical answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You missplaced your second attribute (text)

```js
var $div = $("<div>", {class: 'myClass', text: 'Some text'});
$("body").append($div)
```

```css
.myClass {
  background-color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```